# Multi-Page Event Registration?

Tags: civievent, registration

Our event applications use profiles with a lot of fields.  Is there any way within the core of Civi to break up our application page into multiple pages so users don't see one huge form page with so many fields?  Like could we break things up by sets of fields or even by profile?

Or is this the time to start looking into Webform and it's CiviCRM integration module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some webform_civicrm examples to get you started:

[How to Create webform_civicrm Registrations with: single Ticket vs Table options and Create Contact Records for all Participants](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/how-to-create-webform-civicrm-registrations-with-single-ticket-vs-table-options)

[Webform Event Fees in Combination](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/webform-event-fees-in-combination)

[How do I configure the new recurring contribution feature in Webform CiviCRM module?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/how-do-i-configure-the-new-recurring-contribution-feature-in-webform-civicrm-mod)

You can make easily make really nice looking pages like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely the time to start looking into Webform and it's CiviCRM integration module! It provides page breaks and much more which is not possible with CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  It seems like a very promising module!